# Strange String Behavior

Tags: c, sockets, resolve

I'm trying to verify that a URL input by a user is in the required format, in this case I am trying to remove the `http://` if it is present but I am encountering some very strange problems...

if I feed the function "`www.google.com`" or "`http://www.google.com`" everything goes as expected! However if I feed it something that is not a valid URL (e.g. potato) it returns gibberish located in memory...

Why this is not necissarily a problem it definitely is NOT expected program behavior, and I have no idea why it's behaving this way...

```
Enter URL: potato

Error! Could not resolve ip address for host: ╪☻ï*** Process returned 1 ***
Press any key to continue...
```

Here is the function in question:

```
char *bldurl(const char *url)
{
    char *nurl;
    int ch = 0, i = 0;

    if(chksbstr(url, "http://") < 0)
    {
        if(!(nurl = malloc(strln(url) + 8)))
        {
            printf("\nError! Memory allocation failed while appending URL!");
            return 0x00;
        }
        nurl[ch] = 'h';
        nurl[++ch] = 't';
        nurl[++ch] = 't';
        nurl[++ch] = 'p';
        nurl[++ch] = ':';
        nurl[++ch] = '/';
        nurl[++ch] = '/';
        for(++ch; i <= strln(url); ch++, i++) nurl[ch] = url[i];
        nurl[--ch] = 0x00; 
    }
    else
    {
        if(!(nurl = malloc(strln(url) + 1)))
        {
            printf("\nError! Memory allocation failed while appending URL!");
            return 0x00;
        }
        for(i = 0; i <= strln(url); i++) nurl[i] = url[i];
        nurl[i + 1] = 0x00;
    }
    return nurl;
}
```

And here is the portion of my code that returns that particular error message:

```
    if(!(hostip = gethostbyname(hostname)))
    {
        free(hostname);
        free(url);
        printf("\nError! Could not resolve ip address for host: %s", hostname);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0x00;
    }
```

`hostname` in the above code is the return value from the for mentioned function.

I'm really not sure what to think.

Comment: Who wrote the `chksbstr()` function?  What does it do and return?  Who wrote the `strln()` function?  What does it do and return?  The `for (i = 0; i < strln(url); i++)` idiom is bad; it executes `strln()` on each iteration, which makes the algorithm quadratic in the length of the string (assuming `strln()` is really an alternative to `strlen()` — one which is virtually guaranteed to be slower than the system's `strlen()` function).

Comment: I did and it returns the location of the first element of a substring inside a string. `chksbstr("foobar", "bar");` would return `3`

Comment: this mixture of pre and post ++ and -- is incomprehensible.   Adopt a convention and stick to it.  I recommend using post++ only, so a[b++] is always used to store the next character.

Comment: Your code won't add a `http://` to the front of a string such as `/abc/def/http://example.com/widgets`.  You'll have to decide whether that matters.  I recommend using the standard string handling functions from `<string.h>`; they are usually optimized, and often treated as inline functions, avoiding the overhead of a system call.

Comment: This is some of the worst string handling code I have seen for over 20 years. Your loops involving `strln()` (a) use a non-library function where a library function would do, (b) should loop while `<`, not `<=`, and (c) shouldn't call a function at all. You can replace most of the first block after the `malloc()` with `strcat(strcpy(nurl, "http://",), url)`, and the second with `strcpy(nurl, url)`. 11 lines of code (that should have been more with proper formatting) replaced by two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling a 'free' on hostname and then trying to print it out; of course it will be something unreadable! You should really print it then free it, I guess.

Comment: ahhh duuuuh Wow I guess I have been staring at this too long so obvious thanks!

Comment: No problem :) These things happen!

Answer (score 4):

You can't free hostname and then print it.